# Get only wikitext without JSON from Wikipedia API

Tags: wikipedia-api

Does the Wikipedia API have some endpoint or parameter to return only the wikitext of a page or a section of a page in the HTTP response body (i.e. without the JSON around it?) In this case it could use HTTP status codes to signal an error. The point would be to simplify parsing (no JSON).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not technically part of the API but it's possible:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_York_meteorite?action=raw
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cape_York_meteorite?action=raw&section=0

Comment: Awesome! And the URLs are simpler than those of the advertised API as well :)

Comment: Also properly returns a HTTP 404 error code in case the article is not found: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_such_page?action=raw